# issue in special character converting in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have use ajax to get a code from the database.

In my database shows my answer Nmap –T4 –F 10.15.0.0/24

and when ajax get that it shows Nmap �T4 �F 10.15.0.0/24 in my console.
I have use decodeEntities() for that but it is not working. I have put my coe below.

```js
$.post('functions.php', {answer: answer, ID: ID, action: action, email: email, TestName:TestName}, function(response)                   
{
    var data = decodeEntities(response);
    console.log(data);
                   
});   

function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
  var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
  return textArea.value;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
function category_array($con,$quiz_category){
$final_array = array();
foreach ($quiz_category as $row) {
    $category = find_categoryname($row);
    //print_r($category); die();
    $query ="SELECT * FROM `$row` WHERE `ID` IN(18,205,166)";
    $query_result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query_result)) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)){
            $row["question_category"] = $category;
            $final_array[] = utf8_converter($row);
            //print_r($row); die();
        }
    }
    //$final_array[] = $result_array;
}
return $final_array;
```

}

```
function utf8_converter($array){
array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
    if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
    }
}); 
return $array;
```

}

Comment: Make sure that your web page is using UTF8 (add `<meta charset="utf-8">` to your `<head>`) and also check that your database and PHP are working with UTF8. If you cannot modify the source, convert to UTF the output with `utf8_encode()`.

Comment: Also check your IDE is set to UTF-8 with LF line endings, so all of your actual PHP scripts are also in the correct encoding. Also make sure your DB is in utf8, tables, columns, etc! UTF-8 all the things!

Comment: I have already use UTF-8 in my PHP output please check again in my code